# My project is connecting to mysql database on my local tomcat server 6 but not connecting on tomcat6 in hosting platform

Tags: java, tomcat7, tomcat6, mysql-connector

My project is working fine on my local machine. I am using Private JVM hosting provided by unlimitedgb.com, The project is working fine on my eclipse with tomcat server 6 but when i deploy project on the tomcat server6 provided in NGASI Panel, it is not connecting to database. i had verified the connection string many times. i had exported mysql file as .sql file to the phpmyadmin panel provided in the control panel verified the username and password, database name and port number codded in the "dblayer.java" (myproject/Java Resources :src/com.my.classes) several times.

I am using "mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar" as well as java jason.jar as additional libraries for my project. both files are placed on "myproject/WebContent/WEB-INF/ib/" and which is added to "myproject/Java Resources:src/Libraries/ from above location. I am also using JRE System Library [jre7] in which the "mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar" is present by default but i had added the mysql connector as it is not present in the apache tomcat6 present at my hosting platform. the json.jar is working fine on the server in hosting platform. i had uploaded my project as war file and deployed in apache tomcat server 6 provided by hosting. there is no error showing project is deploying propely but the project is not getting connected with my database. please help me to fix this.

Comment: You are using shared hosting or dedicated server (in which you can access logs/catalina.out)

Comment: Java private JVM Hosting, https://www.unlimitedgb.com/java-private-jvm.html. I can acess logs created by apache tomcat6 from NGASI panel

Comment: You should check your logs and best way to put a simple jsp with jdbc code page and directly hit to that jsp to get the trace so you can confirm the problem. Is it related to connection or something else.

Comment: @ankitkatiyar91 There is no log created or n error message showing. I dont know why it is not getting connected.

Comment: Write a small piece of code in a jsp. All the steps of jdbc they hit to that jsp. with wrap a code in try catch with throwable.
Print complete stack trace like this.
<%}catch(Throwable t) {t.printStackTrace(response.getWriter());}%>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a jsp and try to hit on this

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Start Test<br>
<% try{ %>
<%
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname","user","Passowrd");
            out.println("Connected Successfully");
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement=con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM admin");
            ResultSet rst=preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while(rst.next()){
                out.print("<br/>"+" "+rst.getString(1)+"  "+rst.getString(2)+"  "+rst.getString(3));
            }

            preparedStatement=con.prepareStatement("SELECT count(*),admin_id,username from admin a WHERE username='ankit' AND pwd=md5('ankit')");
            rst=preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while(rst.next()){
                out.print("<br/>"+" "+rst.getString(1)+"  "+rst.getString(2)+"  "+rst.getString(3));
            }
%>
<%}catch(Throwable t) {t.printStackTrace(response.getWriter());}%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i have got the response that the database is not accessible. i had forwarded the message to hosting provider support team and they fixed it.